# assembly wrong character display

Tags: assembly, x86

```
.data

list db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,0
[...]
    lea si,list
[...]
mov al,[si]
    division:
    mov cx,10
    mov dx,0
    div cx
    mov bx,dx
    mov dl,al
    mov ah,2
    add dl,30h
    int 21h

    mov dx,bx
    mov ah,2
    add dl,30h
    int 21h; print [list]
```

[...]

why was the result show ▂5 
before the division, I had even try "mov al,1" and the answer still the same
  ▂5

Comment: Works fine for me when I build a .COM file (I get `01` as the output). Which memory model are you using? Perhaps you forgot to initialize the `DS` register.

Comment: wait, what's DS register function in this situation?
I'm not so understand about it.
Or you means DX register?

Comment: No I mean the `DS` segment register. You should make sure that it's actually pointing to your data segment.

Comment: so what should I do to improve it?
here's my full code
[https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nnupPgAfprj4rz6XQ2QmO7jhtCU9XTEhKYRTCmT6U3M/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: actually I wish to write a code for the multiply of 16
but the result doesn't seems to be correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use a word sized division you have to initialize the AH register to zero in this particular case.

Alternatively you could use byte sized division!

EDIT

```
mov al,[si]
mov ah,0     ;***NEW***
division:
mov cx,10
mov dx,0
div cx
```

Comment: which part should I initialize the AH register to zero? here's my full code [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nnupPgAfprj4rz6XQ2QmO7jhtCU9XTEhKYRTCmT6U3M/edit?usp=sharing]]

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: so the problem was cause by the previous print code which is [mov ah,09h] ?and the problem solved, thanks~